# How to set value to non-empty cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Hi I´m trying to change a cell value when another cell is edited. It actually works but only when the cell I want to write in is empty. here is the code:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  if (sheetName == 'Functional Tests') {
    Logger.log('You are in Functional Tests');

    var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    Logger.log('Active cell: ' + activeCell.getColumn());

    if ( activeCell.getColumn() == 5) {
      Logger.log('Your are working on result column');

      var rowIndex = activeCell.getRowIndex();

      var resultRange = sheet.getRange("E:E");
      var resultCol = 6; //resultRange.getColumn();
      var resultCell = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, resultCol);

      Logger.log('Row index: ' + rowIndex + ' Result col: ' + resultCol);

      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+1', 'dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm');
      resultCell.setValue(date);

    }
  }
}
```

Do somebody know how to solve that problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your issue. But you can eliminate much of the calls to the spreadsheet (getColumn, getActiveCell,..) since all of that is already passed in as parameters of the eventobject (e). So something like this should (also) work:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'Functional Tests' || 
e.range.columnStart !== 5) return;
e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+1', 'dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm'))
}
```

Maybe you get the idea the time stamp doesn't get updated because you don't use seconds in the formatDate ? So changes within the minute won't be reflected that way. You can check by formatting as HH:mm:ss and then see if it changes .. ?